# I can't use the next-auth library

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I wanted to cast authorization in NextJS. To the backend, I had to send the unique code sent to my phone number to the api via nextJS, and from the api I had to receive user data, access and refresh tokens. For this I used next-auth library. but I had problems while using it. [...nextauth].js

```
import { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import axios from "../../lib/axios";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {  
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        code: {
          label: "code",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "code",
        },
      },

      async authorize(credentials, req){        
        const res = await axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "/reg/verify",
            data: {
                code: credentials?.code
            }
        })
        const user = res.data

        if(user){
            return user
        }
        else {
            return null
        }
      }
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({session, token}){
      session.user == token;
      return session
    },
    async jwt({token, user}){
      if(user){
        token = {... token, ...user}
      }
      return token
    }
  }
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

and login funcktion

```
const { data: session, status } = useSession()  

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = async (data) => {
     const result = await signIn("Credentials", {
        code: data.code,
        redirect: true,
        callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/app'
      })
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5p5v.png)

I have the files as follows

Comment: Show your effort, instead of asking for a ready solution. Show specific errors you need help with and example output that you expect.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.